# spaces on mail body when we Open gmail app from iOS url schemes

Tags: ios, swift, gmail, url-scheme

Is it possible to provide spaces or new line or line breaks on gmail compose on URL schemes. I tried both `/n` or `stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding`, but space or lines breaks are not reflecting.

`googlegmail:///co?subject=subject&body= "\n\n\n textfirstname"`

Comment: Use HTML email body and a `<a href="googlegmail:....">Whatever\ntext\nyou\nwant</a>`.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an issue with iOS or url-scheme. You need to use html tag to set new line. For HTML there are `<br/>` or `<br />` which are used to break line. Use this tag instead of \n.

As per you code it should looks like this:

```
Whatever<br/>text<br/>you<br/>want
```

I hope this will be useful to you.

Comment: I tried still its displaying Whatever<br/>text<br/>you<br/>want on gmail compose. even tried with %0D%0A  as well as a few other options.

Comment: Is this issue with Gmail app as i found tis link: https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/GB7Ufj6u3zM;context-place=topicsearchin/gmail/category$3Aiphone-ipad-or-ipod%7Csort:relevance%7Cspell:false